# In Flutter, using await stores data correctly, but not collection name and not using await does not store data correctly, but correct collection name

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

My current code uses:

```
var currentUID = await database.getCurrentUserID();
```

Running this function with await on this line of code stores data in Firestore with correct user ID but time is always set to 0:
[image]

```
Future<void> addUserTime() async {
  var currentUID = await database.getCurrentUserID();

  return await database.workoutCollection
      .doc(currentUID.toString())
      .set({
        'Workout Time': format(duration),
      })
      .then((value) => print('Time added'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Failed to add time to database'));
}
```

Without using await like the previous line of code like this:

```
var currentUID = database.getCurrentUserID();
```

Firestore shows this: This is the firebase output. Wrong UserID from Firebase Authentication, but time is always set to what the user logged:

[image]

```
Future<void> addUserTime() async {
  var currentUID = database.getCurrentUserID();

  return await database.workoutCollection
      .doc(currentUID.toString())
      .set({
        'Workout Time': format(duration),
      })
      .then((value) => print('Time added'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Failed to add time to database'));
}
```

This is my database class where I call the `getCurrentUserID()` function:
[image]

How can I get both the correct UID and correct time the user logged?

Answer (score 1):

`FirebaseAuth` stores the current user once it's authenticated in `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`, if we look into this property we will find that the type is [`User?`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html), not `Future<User?>`, hence you don't need to `await` to get the currentUser, simply:

```dart
return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
```

Additionally, `currentUser?.uid` returns a String, so no need to call `.toString()`.

Assuming that the duration is not 0, with these modifications the code should work, for further reference [here's a DartPad example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e9ed0eee4b7637e23e1e546fc2f78709) that updates a user record based on `currentUser.uid`.